# How to aggregate in R ignoring some rows for some fields, and not ignoring them for others?

Tags: r, aggregate

```
city qA qB qC
0001  1  1  5
0001  3  1  3
0002  2  0 NA
0002  2  0 NA
0002  4  1  1
0002  4  1  3
```

I'd like to agreggate this list by city, with the mean values for each other field. As you can see, question C is only answered if question B is 1. What I want as a result is:

```
city qA qB  qC
0001  2  1   4
0002  3 0.5  2
```

I tried removing the lines with qB==0, but this will change the mean for qA. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple actually:

```
aggregate(xx[-1], by=list(xx$city), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `aggregate`, with *both* the arguments `na.action=na.pass` and `na.rm=TRUE`. The former tells `aggregate` not to remove rows where NAs are present; and the latter is the action that the aggregating function should take.

```
aggregate(cbind(qA, qB, qC) ~ city, df, mean, na.action=na.pass, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: If na.rm = TRUE only removes the values from the mean calculation (not the whole row from the list), na.action=na.pass don't become unnecessary?